# Javascript - updating array values by adding the previous value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

`arr=[20, 40, 40, 40]` and I want to update it to`arr=[20, 60, 100, 140]`

I don't want to update the first value but the following values should be that value plus the value before it in the array

I sort of have it working here but it has to add the previous value after its updated from the previous loop and I'm having to add the first value separately at the end.

```js
let arr = [20, 40, 40, 40]

let arrUpdate = []

for(let n=0; n<arr.length; n++){
  arrUpdate.push(arr[n] + (arr[n-1]))
}

arrUpdate[0] = arr[0]

console.log(arrUpdate)
```

Comment: Try looking into a fold (reduce in JS lingo)

Comment: Or, even better, a *scan*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map new sums by taking a sum variable with a starting value of zero.

```js
let arr = [20, 40, 40, 40],
    sum = 0,
    result = arr.map(v => sum += v);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let arr = [20, 40, 40, 40]

let result = arr.reduce((r,c,i) => (r.push(i ? c + r[i-1] : c), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

And get the running sum from the previous element in the accumulator.